# Hibernate mapping of multiple columns constraint

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Can you guys tell me how to map a combination of columns as a constraint in hbm? 
I performed query below in database but got no idea how it should be done in my hbm.xml class

```
    ALTER TABLE USERS add CONSTRAINT NODUPLICATE UNIQUE (NAME, AGE, STATUS);
```

Do I just put unique = true

```
    <property column="NAME" name="name" type="string" unique="true"/>
```

in every field?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html):

> The  element allows the definition of a named, logical
>   grouping of the properties of a class. The most important use of the
>   construct is that it allows a combination of properties to be the
>   target of a property-ref. It is also a convenient way to define a
>   multi-column unique constraint.

This means you can nest multiple property inside a properties tag

```
<properties unique="true">
    <property column="NAME" name="name" type="string"/>
    //your others properties for the uniqueness
</properties>
```

Comment: is it okay not to follow column sequence? Like my unique columns are one column apart from the other. eg. "NAME, AGE, STATUS", i'll put name and status inside properties tag, while age is not enclose in that same property.

Comment: I also need to put "name" attribute inside properties right? What's the use of this? Do i map the name to the constraint name in my db?

Comment: yes to the first question and name for properties is just the logical name of the grouping. It is not an actual property name. yes you can map it to the constraint name in db for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is fine. It is from doc gave by Zeromus:

```
<column name="column_name" length="N" precision="N" scale="N" not-null="true|false" unique="true|false" unique-key="multicolumn_unique_key_name" index="index_name" sql-type="sql_type_name" check="SQL expression" default="SQL expression"/>
```

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @Igor Trześniewski .